# Get value of selected radio-button?

Tags: jquery

How do I get the value of the selected radio-button and output it inside the value of the hidden input field "selectedquantity"?

```html
<div class="quantityselect">
  <input type="radio" id="quantity0" name="radiobutton" value="50">
  <label for="quantity0">
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="quantity1" name="radiobutton" value="100">
  <label for="quantity1">
  </label>
</div>


<input id="selectedquantity" type="hidden" name="quantity" value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the checked value in your hidden value, you could use the following code:

```
$('#selectedquantity').val($("[name='radiobutton']:checked").val());
```

Wrap it in a `change` event, and it should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("[name='radiobutton']").change(function() {
    $('#selectedquantity').val($("[name='radiobutton']:checked").val());
  });
});
```

You can see a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/k5y9gyf3/3/

Comment: You need to be more careful, your demo doesn't work because your code contains a syntax error: `'[name='radiobutton']'`.

Comment: Ups, you are rght @PatrickRoberts. I've fixed it now. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

First you want to attach a `change` event handler to the radio buttons. Then, when it is called, you want to grab the value of the radio and set it as the value of the input. The selectors I've used might need to change, but the logic is there.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    $('#selectedquantity').val($(this).val());
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantityselect">
  <input type="radio" id="quantity0" name="radiobutton" value="50">
  <label for="quantity0">
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="quantity1" name="radiobutton" value="100">
  <label for="quantity1">
  </label>
</div>

<!-- un-hidden for demonstration -->
<input id="selectedquantity" type="text" name="quantity" value="">
```

Comment: I'd recommend that your selector for the radio be `input[name="radiobutton"]` so that the hidden field doesn't receive the value of other groups that could be in the document.

Comment: Well that's why I mentioned the selectors may have to change - that's OPs job to work out which selectors to use based on the full context of his script, I'm just providing the logic he should use

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1) Use `.change()` event to check when radio button clicked

2) `$('input[name=radiobutton]:checked').val()` to get the selected value of radio button

```js
 $('.quantityselect input').on('change', function() {
       alert($('input[name=radiobutton]:checked').val()); 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantityselect">
  <input type="radio" id="quantity0" name="radiobutton" value="50">
  <label for="quantity0">
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="quantity1" name="radiobutton" value="100">
  <label for="quantity1">
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','input[type="radio"]', function(e){
    $(document)find('#selectedquantity').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! Use `input[name=radiobutton]`

```
$('input[name=radiobutton]').click(function(){
    //alert($(this).val());
  $('#selectedquantity').val($(this).val());
  alert($('#selectedquantity').val());
});
```

Whichever option you select will get stored in the hidden field

**[Here is the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/7h873d95/)**